# python client and server socket programming in a single script

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, sockets, network-programming

I have to combine client script and server script in a single script , and run both client and server from the same file itself.
I can create both separately but unable to create both in a sibgle script. please somebody help me , I'm stuck in this for the last two days.

I've tried this code (taken from stack overflow), but it's not working on my machine.
**Someone please help !!!**
And please also let me know what this `!r` in `{msg!r}` does ?
I'm using python 3.9.6

```
import asyncio
async def echo_client(msg):
    reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection('127.0.0.1',5050)
    print(f'Send:{msg!r}')
    writer.write(msg.encode())
    await writer.drain()

    data = await reader.read(100)
    print(f'Recieved: {data.decode()!r}')

    print('close the connection')
    writer.close()
    await writer.wait_closed()


async def handle_echo(reader, writer):
    data = await reader.read(100)
    message = data.decode()
    addr = writer.get_extra_info('peername')

    print(f'Recieved {message!r} from {addr!r}')

    print(f'Send:{message!r}')
    writer.write(data)
    await writer.drain()

    print('close the connection')
    writer.close()

async def main():
    server = await asyncio.start_server(handle_echo,'127.0.0.1',5050)

    addr = server.sockets[0].getsockname()
    print(f'Serving on {addr}')

    async with server:
        await server.serve_forever()

# asyncio.run(echo_client("hello server"))
asyncio.run(main())
```

Answer (score 0):

**This seems to work **
Please have a look at it and post your suggestions

```
import socket, threading
from time import sleep

host_ip = socket.gethostbyname("www.python.org")
port = 5051
print("host is ", host_ip)
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print("socket successfully created")
s.bind(('', port))
print("socket bind to %s" % (port))

s.listen(5)
print("socket is listening")



def server_func():
    while True:
        c, addr = s.accept()
        print("got connection from", addr)

        c.send("[SERVER]: Thank you for connecting\n".encode())
        c.send("[SERVER]: This is your server sending the message\n\n".encode())
        print(c.recv(1024).decode())
        break

def client_func():
    s2 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s2.connect(("localhost", port))
    print("\n")
    print(s2.recv(1024).decode())
    print(s2.recv(1024).decode())
    s2.send("[CLIENT]: *****Hello Server, This is client*****".encode())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=server_func)
    t1.start()
    sleep(1)
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=client_func)
    t2.start()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).